# Why does my Bootstrap navbar menu item wrap to the line below when there is centered text

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-5

I have a very simple Bootstrap navbar, its the basic example on the Bootstrap website at https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/navigation/navbar/#docsTabsOverview.

I want to add some custom text to the center of the navbar which I have managed to do but the centered text seems to push the menu item "Contact Us" on to two lines and I cannot seem to keep it on the same line as the other menu items "About" and "Services".

Here is my HTML code file index.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <title>JU Physiotherapy</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" />
    <!-- Google Fonts Roboto -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" />
    <!-- MDB -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mdb.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />


</head>

<body>
    <!-- Start your project here-->
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav data-mdb-navbar-init class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
        <!-- Container wrapper -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Toggle button -->
            <button data-mdb-collapse-init class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-mdb-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>

            <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- Navbar brand -->
                <a class="navbar-brand mt-2 mt-lg-0" href="index.html">
                    <img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="images/logo.png" alt="" loading="lazy" />
                </a>
                <!-- Left links -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Left links -->
            </div>
            <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->

            <div class="container-md d-flex justify-content-center">
                Hello
            </div>

            <!-- Right elements -->
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <!-- Icon -->
                <a class="text-reset me-3" target="_blank"
                    href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100090193406935">
                    <img style="width:45px;height:45px" src="images/facebook.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="text-reset me-3" target="_blank"
                    href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/james-underwood-269a06118/">
                    <img style="width:45px;height:45px;" src="images/linkedin.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="text-reset me-3" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/juphysiotherapy/">
                    <img style="width:38px;height:38px;" src="images/instagram.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="text-reset me-3" target="_blank" href="https://www.whatsapp.com/">
                    <img style="width:40px;height:40px;" src="images/whatsapp.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="text-reset me-3" href="#">
                    <img style="width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:20px;" src="images/profile-pic-current.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Container wrapper -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Navbar -->

    <!-- End your project here-->


    </div>

    <!-- MDB -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.umd.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is my CSS file styles.css

```
body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the page on Google Chrome.

[image: Screenshot of web page]

Answer (score 0):

The container with the text "Hello" (`<div class="container-md d-flex justify-content-center">Hello</div>`) does not leave space for the top menu items, so menu item text must to wrap. So you need replace the class of container `container-md` for a column (eg.`col-md-6`).

Recomendation: Better use [official bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/)